# How do I (temporarily) cancel centering?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

There I was, a-merrily tracing through the depths of [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s code on the trail of the Dreaded Overprint Hurler of Bexhill-on-Sea, when I came across Something Completely Different.  It looked like a cross between a vbox and a centering, but horribly, horribly mutated.

Desiring to slay this monstrous beastie before it could wreak havoc, I studied it and its relatives (from a safe distance).  Its behaviour is strange, but by caging it I could see some patterns in its responses to basic stimuli.  Eventually, I realised that if I could but introduce some genetic mutation which temporarily switched off the `\centering` gene then it could be made safe and I could resume my quest to track down the Overprint.

---

In less prosaic language, while investigating [Overprint environment inside tikz node: unexpected alignment of content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61035/86) I figured out that the problem was due to the interaction between the `center` environment (aka `\centering`) and how `beamer` implements the `overprint` environment.  What `beamer` does is gather all the possible versions of the `overprint` environment into `vbox`es containing `minipage`s of the prescribed width.  It then sets the correct one (according to the overlay specification) but with the height and depth of the biggest one.  However, if the `overprint` environment is contained within a `center` environment, something a little odd ensues.  It would appear that the `vbox` containing the `minipage` environment has already taken into account the `center` environment and so consists of the `minipage` environment at the centre of the line, with the requisite spacing fore (and presumably aft).  But when the `vbox` is set, it is still within the `center` environment so picks up a *new* indentation.  This wouldn't matter, except for the fact that the `vbox`'s width is adjusted to the prescribed width so TeX adds yet more horizontal space to shove the `vbox` back into the centre of the line (or so it thinks).

Given that all of this is going on inside a `beamer` overprint environment, and I don't want to muck around with that code, the simplest solution seemed to be to turn off the `\centering` just before the `overprint` environment (and, given my reading of the original question, turn it back on again inside).  But `\centering` seems to be a one-way trap: there's `\centering`, `\rightragged`, `\leftragged`, but no `\backtonormal`.

Here's some code to play around with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newbox\mybox

\begin{document}

\setbox\mybox=\vbox\bgroup\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4cm}hello
world\end{minipage}}\egroup

\centering

\wd\mybox=4cm

\fbox{\box\mybox}

\setbox\mybox=\vbox\bgroup\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4cm}hello
world\end{minipage}}\egroup

\wd\mybox=4cm

\fbox{\box\mybox}

\setbox\mybox=\vbox\bgroup\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4cm}\centering hello
world\end{minipage}}\egroup

\wd\mybox=4cm

\fbox{\box\mybox}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4cm}hello world\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4cm}\centering hello world\end{minipage}}


\end{document}
```

Here's what I get from that:

[image: boxes and centring and alignment]

Comment: The package `ragged2e` provides `\justifying`

Comment: editorial niggle -- the first section is "less prosaic", i.e., purple; the second section is the "more prosaic" (dictionary definition: "humdrum") version.  now, if you'd said "poetic", ...  beware the jabberwock, my son.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You have a choice of responses.  Press "1" for "I put that in just so that you'd leave an editorial comment.".  Press "2" for "I was being ironic.  (I am British, after all).".  Press "3" for "I'd've gotten away with it too if it weren't for you pesky AMS staff.".  Press "9" for English.

Comment: how about "4" for "the pesky tugboat editor just won't let anybody get away with anything, no matter how trivial."

Comment: @barbarabeeton Wasn't that "3"?  s/AMS/tugboat/.

Comment: no, tugboat is a publication of tug; not connected with ams.  i just happen to be associated with both -- employed by ams, tug volunteer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hence the `s/AMS/tugboat/`.  Or perhaps "Press "3" for "I'd've gotten away with it too if it weren't for you pesky `\ifx\user\barbarabeeton\relax tugboat staff\else kids\fi`."." to make the allusion clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The package `ragged2e` provides enhanced versions of `\centering`, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` (that you may or may not like), but above all makes available the command

```
\justifying
```

that undoes the above declarations.

Comment: I think this one should be at the top for sheer "ease of use".  Whilst I tend to go for the more hackish solutions, I suspect that others wanting the same feature would be best served by the `ragged2e` package.  Hence I'm accepting this one, though all were useful solutions.

Answer (score 9):

since you are in a box already (so page breaking isn't a concern) can't you just do

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
```

centering a full width box is a no-op and the text inside the box will be justified.

Comment: That works, but it took me a while to figure out why.  I thought that that ought to put a vertical box of width `\textwidth` at the corresponding location (which would be bad), but it doesn't.  The reason seems to be because `overprint` puts its stuff in a vertical box.  If I force a horizontal box in there somewhere then the inner box ends up being `\textwidth` and so the resulting box is too wide.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\normaljustify{%
  \let\\\@centercr\rightskip\z@skip \leftskip\z@skip%
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\centering\lipsum[1]
\normaljustify\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a parindent then set it in the definition.

Comment: In the question where I got this from, I got some `Underful hbox`es until I put `\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil`.  I also don't understand why the double backslash is let to `\@centercr`.  Isn't that what it already is (from the `\centering`)?

Comment: yes, you're right if you have `\centering` before

Comment: So wouldn't I want to let it back to whatever-it-normally-is?  (which, I find, is different in `beamer` as there whatever-it-normally-is *is* the same as `\@centercr`)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil`?