# Table caption with centered small-caps title and fully-justifed description

Tags: tables, captions

I often see tables with centered titles and fully-justified descriptions. Here is an example.

[image: Table caption I would like (i.e., centered title and fully-justified description.]

I know how to use the `caption` package to alter the label and title, but I can't figure out how to get the description fully justified. Instead, my description adopts the `\centering` that I use to get the table centered.

What is the best way to do this? Here is my best attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{This could win me the Nobel Prize in Economics.}
    {\noindent Fine, this could win me the Nobel \emph{Memorial} Prize in Economic Sciences.~\lipsum[1]}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc}
    \toprule
    xx&1&2&3\\
    xx&1&2&3\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But this gives me a centered description.

[image: My failed attempt with centered description.]

I see there is a `threeparttable` package, but I don't want footnotes. I would like the description to immediately follow the title.

Comment: In essence, you're probably asking the same as [How do I (temporarily) cancel `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61112/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you may be using such descriptions for figures regularly, [define a macro to take care of the formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764); this includes keeping the text justified using `\justifying` (from [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=sc]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}

\newcommand{\figuredesc}[1]{% Figure description
  \begingroup
  \par
  \justifying\small
  \noindent #1
  \par
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{This could win me the Nobel Prize in Economics.}

  \figuredesc{Fine, this could win me the Nobel \emph{Memorial} Prize in Economic Sciences.~\lipsum[1]}

  \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
    \hline
    A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    B & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

To my opinion the simplest way is to move this long explanation in the first row of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{This could win me the Nobel Prize in Economics.}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize 
    Fine, this could win me the Nobel \emph{Memorial} Prize in Economic Sciences.~\lipsum[1]}\\
    \toprule
xx  &   1 &   2 &   3\\
xx  &   1 &   2 &   3\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `threeparttablex`, an extension of `threeparttable`, which allows you to insert table notes anywhere in a `longtable`, and `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of longtable to `tabularx`.

Note the syntax of `threeparttablex` is slightly differnt from that of `threeparttable`. With `ltablex`, the caption has to be inserted within the table, as with `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttablex,  ltablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
  \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]
    \item[\hskip-\fontdimen2\font]Fine, this could win me the Nobel \emph{Memorial} Prize in Economic Sciences.~\lipsum[1]
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}%
    \caption{This could win me the Nobel Prize in Economics.}\\
    \insertTableNotes\\
    \addlinespace%
    \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    xx & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    xx & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]