# Centering a line above a one-page document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I am writing a one-page research statement that goes basically like this:

Research Statement, First name, Last name

Statement here

I'm trying not to use a title, since it's bigger in font and has a bit of spacing from my first paragraph which I don't want.

Instead of using a title, I tried just

```
\centering Research Statement, First name, Last name
```

but this seems to have the effect of centering all of my subsequent paragraphs.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Hi @PaulGessler, yes I've tried that but it doesn't work...

Comment: `{\par\centering This Is My Title\par}` should do the trick. `\centering` is a declaration more like `\bfseries` than `\textbf{<text>}`. There is also `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, of course.

Comment: Awesome @jon.  Just a quick follow-up:  how could I give a line of white space between my first sentence and the centered title?  Thanks so much,

Comment: Well, the environment will provide whitespace by default. Otherwise you can try the commands `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`. There is also `\vspace{<length>}` to give a specific amount of space. You may want to consider using `\noindent`, too, for the first paragraph following the title.

Comment: @user58865: Note that jon also suggested `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck with the research!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I (temporarily) cancel `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61112/5764)

Comment: @jon Do you want to add a short answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B -- Sure. (Done.)

Answer (score 1):

(Based on earlier comments.)

If you want to have some vertical space automatically added as you centre some text, then the `center` environment is normally the way to go:

```
\begin{center}
Research Statement, First name, Last name
\begin{center}
```

Note that you can easily add paragraphs as normal:

```
\begin{center}
Research Statement

First name Last name
\begin{center}
```

or, if needed, use `\\` to create a `newline`, but not `\newline`:

```
\begin{center}
Research Statement\\ % forcing linebreaks in this way should be avoided in most cases, however
First name Last name
\begin{center}
```

You can also use the `\centering` command, but you must be careful to use groups to avoid the subsequent lines being centred as well:

```
{\par\centering <this is the centered text>\par}
```

or:

```
{\par\centering <this is the % here we add a new paragraph the usual way: by adding a blank line between paragraphs

 centered text>\par}
```

Note the use of `\par`, which is needed to make `\centering` 'work' the way you probably expect.

By itselt, `\centering` adds no vertical space before or after it, so you need to combine it with vertical spacing commands commands such as `\bigskip`, `\medskip`, `\smallskip`, or `\vspace`

```
Some preliminary text...

\bigskip

{\par\centering <this is the centered text>\par}

\smallskip

More text ...
```

But this starts becoming *ad hoc* 'coding' and usually should be limited to pretty isolated instances. (E.g., using them once or twice on a title page is probably better than designing a whole custom environment [unless you enjoy designing], but using them a dozen times across a whole document is liable to make the document inconsistent in its style and harder to maintain, overall.)